# asp.net template not found after installed "monodevelop" IDE on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, asp.net, monodevelop, ubuntu-16.04

i currently installed mono-complete and monodevelop from the mono official site and entered this commands below

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get install mono-complete

 sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

on my ubuntu 16.04
but when i open monodevelop IDE and try to create a new solution don't find the asp.net templates as expected therefor am not allowed to create web projects like asp.net mvc! the only templates what i get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp3mf.png)

after that i removed mono packages from synaptic and reinstalled it again from ubuntu software center but i got the same result

and this is what i got in terminal when i run sudo apt-get update

```
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ermshiperete_monodevelop-beta_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 6F242C166A1B440BA3C43CBD48B6803E839ECBBE (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/download.mono-project.com_repo_debian_dists_wheezy_InRelease: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF (weak digest)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't install all MonoDevelop bits yet. Please search Ubuntu repo to see which are the missing ones. Even the NUnit integration requires another package to be installed.

Comment: it was working fine before i upgrade my ubuntu version , is this issue related to ubuntu version ?

Answer (score 13):

I can confirm that the suggestion by Abu above does work.

Tonight I have tested it on a clean Ubuntu 16.04 (Mate) instance running within VirtualBox, and I have been able to create a new MVC/Razor project, and can compile my (quite extensive) MVC app.

Setup using the following commands, as per the Mono Project documentation (at http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/), but with the change from wheezy to alpha.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian alpha main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, install Mono itself:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel mono-complete ca-certificates-mono mono-xsp4
```

Then, to install the specific version of MonoDevelop that gives you a working ASP.NET add-in:

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop=5.10.0.871-0xamarin2
```

**UPDATE:** I have written this up as a blog post on my website, so hopefully this brings further attention to this issue, which really shouldn't be happening in an LTS. The full post is at https://brendaningram.com/article/how-to-fix-monodevelop-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same problem with ubuntu 16.04, and solved it by doing the following :

first add alpha updates channel

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian alpha main" |    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin-alpha.list
sudo apt-get update
```

then force install this version of monodevelop

```
5.10.0.871-0xamarin2
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually it's completely unnecessary to add alpha updates channel. You still can use [release channel](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives). Just do this:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete ca-certificates-mono mono-xsp4
sudo apt-get install monodevelop=5.10.0.871-0xamarin2
```

Then asp.net adding will be installed into MonoDevelop.

Comment: Now, it reprts an error `E: Version '5.10.0.871-0xamarin2' for 'monodevelop' was not found`

Answer (score 2):

As Arsenius said you don't need add alpha updates, it worked for me, also I didnt need to uninstall all the packages. I just did this:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove monodevelop
sudo apt-get purge monodevelop
sudo apt-get install monodevelop=5.10.0.871-0xamarin2
```

Comment: You should add the "install" argument to : sudo apt-get monodevelop=5.10.0.871-0xamarin2, sudo apt-get install monodevelop=5.10.0.871-0xamarin2